# Reject PDF files with embedded JavaScript code during file uploads. (XSS)

Tags: c#, angular, security, .net-core, xss

I have an application and I am using `Angular` for the client-side and `.NET core` for the server-side.
The application allows users to upload PDF files to the system and they can be viewedlater. How can I reject PDF files with embedded `JavaScript` code during file uploads to prevent Cross-Site Scripting(XSS)?

Answer (score 0):

Generally no way to know for certain if a client has a virus/trojan or viral/trojan files for uploading.

The majority of scripted forms may often have such contents (One very good reason not to call those .pdf but say .XFA or .XMP not dumber.PDF)

You can only tell once the file has been uploaded where you can run diagnostics in your lab, to see if the internal scripting is safe (benign) or cancerous.

Putting the onus at the import point is likely to be pointless unless you supply an antivirus uploader, that fully utilises the clients device to disassemble and analyses the clients hard drive sectors as files are uploaded.

There is no way to distinguish %PDF-i`*`fect from %PDF-i`*`fect where one is  **mper** and the other **n**

A message could be simply Please send this form on completion or a JS bomb.

Few script kiddies would be silly to leave a script as simple as this benign one, thus simply looking for /Javascript would only weed out pranksters.

```
6 0 obj
<<
/JavaScript <<
/Names [(AScript) <<
/JS (app.alert\({\r\ncMsg: "Gotcha! Try again!", \r\ncTitle: "Acme Testing Service"\r\n}\);)
/S /JavaScript
>>]
>>
>>
endobj
```